# C# ServicedComponent running out-of-process gets File Not Found exception on one machine

Tags: c#, com+

I've written a stupid-simple ServicedComponent (COM+ component) to run out-of-process and wrap an x86 only COM component on an x64 server. On my test VM (Server 2008 R2) it works fine. On the production box, I get a file not found exception.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>C:\Testapp.exe
>   The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   System.EnterpriseServices.Thunk.Proxy.CoCreateObject(Type
>   serverType, Boolean bQuerySCInfo,
>   Boolean& bIsAnotherProcess, String&
>   uri)    at
>   System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxyAttribute.CreateInstance(Type
>   serverType)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(Type
>   serverType, Object[] props, Boolean
>   bNewObj)    at
>   Testapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\TFS\Testapp\Program.cs:line 11

Line 11 of Program.cs is where I instantiate an object of the COM type that I am wrapping.

Again, This works fine on my x64 Win 7 development machine, and my x64 test VM.
I'm building my component x86, and registering with the 32bit version of regsvcs from a 32bit command prompt.

What on earth am I doing wrong or forgetting?

Comment: To clarify, you have a COM+ component that wraps a native COM component?  If so, are you sure the native COM component exists and is registered on your server?

Comment: Also, have you tried to register your serviced component by installing it into the COM+ catalog via the Component Services tool?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the COM component exists (I tested them both in the same .vbs file).

Is there a difference between using regsvcs.exe and the component services tool?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I've seen a situation where regsvcs.exe did not register the component properly (we got an error trying to instantiate it) on x64 but using the component services tool worked fine.  You could try comparing the registry entries on the different servers to try to see if the component is registered differently on different servers.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, could you please post the solution?

Comment: Never did resolve this one, and have long-since moved on.