# Is it ever appropriate for a component to throw a FIleNotFound exception that doesn't at least include the name of the file?

Tags: c#, clr

Is it ever appropriate for a component to throw a FileNotFound exception that doesn't at least include the name of the file?

Comment: Let me guess - you're dealing with one such component now?

Comment: Indeed I am. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162866/c-servicedcomponent-running-out-of-process-gets-file-not-found-exception-on-one

I just seems like it would much easier to figure out if the exception told me WHAT was missing (or inaccessible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, but please don't. The poor guy trying to figure out what's gone wrong and how to fix it, it drives him absolutely wild.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file in question should remain *invisible* -- like it's none of the user's business to know about it. Yes, that's a bit awkward but it's a legitimate circumstance.

(Not that it justifies throwing a FNFException; a generic "Internal Error" would be more appropriate in this case.)

---

A diverse situation is that of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162866/c-servicedcomponent-running-out-of-process-gets-file-not-found-exception-on-one). The COM+ component doesn't *really* throw a `FileNotFoundException`. It merely informs the runtime about the occurrence of an error through an inespecific `ThrowExceptionForHRInternal()` method. Note that it's (potentially) dealing with an unmanaged component, so all available error details are those provided by the OS -- it may have to resort to API calls such as [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx).

The OS provides some [system error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx) which will reveal the nature of the problem. Unfortunately, at this level there's pretty much what all you'll get... so, no file names this time.

Comment: I suppose this would be OK if it were my app and I could silently report that back through a crash reporter. But, if I changed my question to direct it at the CLR specifically - should any part of the CLR ever do this to us as .Net developers, would you still feel this way?

Comment: Well, I have mixed feelings about it. They may have considered file names as sensitive information, therefore it's fine to omit it from the exception data. By the other hand, it makes debugging very hard.

Comment: @Peter, see my edit regarding the question about the ServicedComponent.

Comment: I disagree with this. At the component level, you ABSOLUTELY should report back as much reasonable information as you can. It's often not appropriate for the FRONT-END to show the complete error, but it would be wildly irresponsible for you to withold information like this from the consuming developer. Case in point, IBM MQ API returns "Error in application.". At that point, I am forced to call in a pay for support. Not cool. Don't be like IBM!

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that if you are writing a component, you shouldn't throw an exception like this. This tightly-couples your clients with your implementation. What I mean is, right now, you are reading from a file, and the consumer has been trained to just catch System.IO.IOException. But what about in your next release when the interface stays the same, but you will go to a web service, instead.

An implementation change on  your side, just became a BREAKING change for your consumer. They now have to re-write their code to catch a FaultException.

What you should do instead if create your own exceptions (just like they do in the .NET Framework). For this, make on like DataSourceEndpointNotFoundException or something generic like that, and you can attach/include the IOException as an inner exception, to give them more of a clue. But this approach future-proofs your code so that if you change implementation, then your clients won't be affected. Hope that helps.